# Multisim 16 counter to 14 counter

Tags: flipflop, counter, multisim

Hello I was wondering if anyone can help me with this 16 counter in multisim. What do I add to limit it at E rather than F? Thank you

[image: 16 counter]

Comment: Do you understand that limiting at E "rather than F" will produce a divide by 15 counter, not divide by 14?

Answer (score -1):

You need a logic gate circuit on the reset of your JK gates which is triggered when the total value is counted.
For example RST = !Q5.Q1.Q2.Q3, which is 1110 or E

! = not

Comment: Putting a gate output on the asynchronous reset will lead to problems with glitches causing false resets. The gate output needs to synchronously reset the JKs.

Comment: Oh indeed, if I'm not wrong a D gate connected to CLK and at output !Q5.Q1.Q2.Q3 of the logic gates should make it.